# Axapta Error :The Configuration "xxxx" could not be found

Tags: startup, axapta

When ever i try to launch the application through citrix. i get the error **"The Configuration "xxxx" could not be found.
Use the Navision Axapta Configuration Utility to verify the configuration.Please restart the Axapta Business Connector before Logging on.**

The Application runs on Axapta and i have im[orted the .xpo files in the Axapta Connector Utility 3.0.

Kindly suggest how to fix the error.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How do you run axapta? Do you run axapta.exe file or launch configuration shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the XPO on the Citrix server and for each user.

The easy way to is incorporate it in the Citrix shortcut it self:

```
"C:\Program Files\Navision\Axapta Client\Bin\ax32.exe" "-regimport=\\File01\Appl\Config\Test.xpo" -regconfig=Test
```

The `-regimport` has the path to the configuration file and `-regconfig` tells Axapta to use that configuration (hopefully the one in the file).